# How to uncheck any checkbox ListItem After FindByText in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, checkboxlist, listbox-control

I have a three Checkbox List on my page and I am adding any checked checkbox list Items to a List Box Control. When I remove any item from the List Box, it automatically UN-checks that list item on my checkbox List.

So far I am finding which checkbox list contains that checkbox and it's working.
But I don't have an idea how I can uncheck that item which contains that text.

What I have tried so far is shown below:

```
if (listboxControl.SelectedIndex > 0)
{
    string na = listboxControl.SelectedItem.Text;
    listboxControl.Items.RemoveAt(listboxControl.SelectedIndex);
    var cb1 = CheckBoxList1.Items.FindByText(na);
    var cb2 = CheckBoxList2.Items.FindByText(na);
    var cb3 = CheckBoxList3.Items.FindByText(na);
    if (cb1 != null) 
    {
           //here how i can Uncheck That Item        
    }
    else if (cb2 != null)
    {
           //here how i can Uncheck That Item 
    }
    else if (cb3 != null)
    {
           //here how i can Uncheck That Item 
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The method [`CheckBoxList1.Items.FindByText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.findbytext(v=vs.110).aspx) will search the
>   collection for a ListItem with a Text property that equals text
>   specified by the text parameter. This method performs a case-sensitive
>   and culture-insensitive comparison. This method does not do partial
>   searches or wildcard searches. If an item is not found in the
>   collection using these criteria, null is returned.

So, the return value of this method will be the required item or null, If it is not `null` then you can use the `Selected` property to check/uncheck the item.

```
if (cb1 != null) 
{
   cb1.Selected = false;
}
```